# Draw a grid like snake and ladder board game in python

Tags: python

I want to draw a normal terminal grid in python or you can just print the numbers in a snake and ladder way. The bottom line will be 1 to 10 in order, the line above that should 11 to 20 but in reverse order and continue this till 100. How can I achieve this using Python? A scalable solution to this would be much appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT** : Ok, I came up with this solution. Is there any other way to achieve it. Maybe a more pythonic way or with less time and space complexity?

```
numbers = [i+1 for i in range(100)]
numbers = numbers[::-1]
levels = [i for i in numbers[::-10]]
is_reversed = False

for level in levels:

    if is_reversed:
        for number in reversed(numbers[level-1:level+9]):
            print('{:4}'.format(number), end='')
    else:
        for number in numbers[level-1:level+9]:
            print('{:4}'.format(number), end='')

    is_reversed = not is_reversed
    print()
```

Comment: Did you give it a try? Any code that you can post?

Comment: Have you learned about loops yet? Any loop tutorial will give you the basic skills required to do this kind of thing.

Comment: I just need the logic behind printing the numbers in reverse order at every alternate line. @Chris

Comment: @AnmolGulati, what is your strategy for printing the numbers in natural order? If you [edit] your question and add the code you already have you'll find that we can provide better help. It's very difficult to answer without any context.

Comment: Edits made. @Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below uses a list comprehension to first make the list, then a second to reverse every other row. The key was the good ol' modulo `%`.

```
rows = [[f'{(n+1) + (i*10):4}' for n in range(10)] for i in range(10)]
rows = reversed([reversed(rows[i]) if i%2 else rows[i] for i in range(len(rows))])

for row in rows:
    print(' | '.join(row))
```

Result:

```
 100 |   99 |   98 |   97 |   96 |   95 |   94 |   93 |   92 |   91
  81 |   82 |   83 |   84 |   85 |   86 |   87 |   88 |   89 |   90
  80 |   79 |   78 |   77 |   76 |   75 |   74 |   73 |   72 |   71
  61 |   62 |   63 |   64 |   65 |   66 |   67 |   68 |   69 |   70
  60 |   59 |   58 |   57 |   56 |   55 |   54 |   53 |   52 |   51
  41 |   42 |   43 |   44 |   45 |   46 |   47 |   48 |   49 |   50
  40 |   39 |   38 |   37 |   36 |   35 |   34 |   33 |   32 |   31
  21 |   22 |   23 |   24 |   25 |   26 |   27 |   28 |   29 |   30
  20 |   19 |   18 |   17 |   16 |   15 |   14 |   13 |   12 |   11
   1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |    5 |    6 |    7 |    8 |    9 |   10
```

#### Edit:

A recent performance test showed me that `enumerate` is more performant than using `range` and indexing. That changes the second line to look like:

```
rows = reversed([reversed(row) if i%2 else row for i, row in enumerate(rows)])
```

Comment: I get an error with the ```f``` in the first line and have to remove it. If i remove it it outputs ```{(n+1) + (i*10):4} | {(n+1) + (i*10):4} | {(n+1) + (i*10):4}```

Comment: That's the new (Python 3.6) string formatting. Replace it to `'{:4}'.format((n+1) + (i*10))` and it should work.

Comment: Yes, the Liter String interpolation was put in place through PEP 498 and was implemented in python 3.6. It will throw an error if you are using an older version. If you are using an older version it should look like `'{:4}'.format((n+1) + (i*10))`

Answer (score 2):

Here i is from 99 to 0 (both inclusive), the code is printing (i + 1) i.e. from 100 to 1

i // 10 will return identical value for 10 consecutive number. Based on weather this value is odd or even, the order of printing is decided.

Here i is from 99 to 0, i.e. descending order. So to print in reverse order, we need to jump with -10 for first column. for second column we need to jump with -9. However for second column the i is also reduced by 1. So we should jump with -8. Here -8 = -10 + 2 in generic way "jump = -10 + 2 (j th column)" Here column number j is from 0 to 9. It is remainder when we divide i with 10.

This is how, we get reverse order at alternate row

```
def snake_ladder():
    for i in range(99, -1, -1):
        if (i // 10) % 2 == 0:
            print("{0:4d}".format(i - 10 + 2 * (10 - (i % 10))), end=" ")
        else:
            print("{0:4d}".format(i + 1), end=" ")
        if i % 10 == 0:
            print("\r")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    snake_ladder()
```

output :

```
 100   99   98   97   96   95   94   93   92   91 
  81   82   83   84   85   86   87   88   89   90 
  80   79   78   77   76   75   74   73   72   71 
  61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68   69   70 
  60   59   58   57   56   55   54   53   52   51 
  41   42   43   44   45   46   47   48   49   50 
  40   39   38   37   36   35   34   33   32   31 
  21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30 
  20   19   18   17   16   15   14   13   12   11 
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
```

Comment: Can you add a small comment on your implementation? Perhaps a summary of the strategy you followed and how you think this solution is better than others.

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in range(1, 101): # 1 - 100
    print ("%03d" % (101 - x,), end = " | ") # make all numbers 3 digits
    if x % 10 == 0: # every ten line output a new line
        print()
```

Output

```
100 | 099 | 098 | 097 | 096 | 095 | 094 | 093 | 092 | 091 | 
090 | 089 | 088 | 087 | 086 | 085 | 084 | 083 | 082 | 081 | 
080 | 079 | 078 | 077 | 076 | 075 | 074 | 073 | 072 | 071 | 
070 | 069 | 068 | 067 | 066 | 065 | 064 | 063 | 062 | 061 | 
060 | 059 | 058 | 057 | 056 | 055 | 054 | 053 | 052 | 051 | 
050 | 049 | 048 | 047 | 046 | 045 | 044 | 043 | 042 | 041 | 
040 | 039 | 038 | 037 | 036 | 035 | 034 | 033 | 032 | 031 | 
030 | 029 | 028 | 027 | 026 | 025 | 024 | 023 | 022 | 021 | 
020 | 019 | 018 | 017 | 016 | 015 | 014 | 013 | 012 | 011 | 
010 | 009 | 008 | 007 | 006 | 005 | 004 | 003 | 002 | 001 |
```

Comment: Every alternate line should be reversed.

Comment: No, have you played snakes and ladder? I want the grid similar to the board of that game.